# PythonのStyleFrameでエクセルに上書きせず追記できるようにしたい

Tags: python, pandas

`StyleFrame` を使ってエクセルに上書きせずに保存したいのですがうまく行きません。

試したことは `with StyleFrame.ExcelWriter(s_path,mode='a') as writer:` です。
これではエラーになってしまって出来ませんでした。

教えていただけたら嬉しいです、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

styleframeはpandasとopenpyxlのラッパーらしいので、`ExcelWriter`はpandasを呼んでいると思われます。

[styleframe](https://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

> A library that wraps pandas and openpyxl and allows easy styling of dataframes.

[Docs » Basic Usage Examples](https://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage_examples.html)

> Creating ExcelWriter object:
>
> ```
> ew = StyleFrame.ExcelWriter(r'C:\my_excel.xlsx')
> sf.to_excel(ew)
> ew.save()
> ```

---

一応pandasのExcelWriterには`mode=`パラメータは有りますが：

[pandas.ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)

> class pandas.ExcelWriter(path, engine=None, **kwargs)
>
> - path : str or typing.BinaryIO
> - engine : str (optional)
> - date_format : str, default None
> - datetime_format : str, default None
> - mode : {'w', 'a'}, default 'w'
> - storage_options : dict, optional

---

以下のstyleframeの仕様文書にはExcelWriterの項目が無く、どのように呼び出しているか(パラメータをそのままpandasに渡しているか？)が不明です。：

[Docs » API Documentation » styleframe](https://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styleframe.html)

ソースコードを見ると`path`以外のパラメータは受け付けていないようですね。

[style_frame.py#L310](https://github.com/DeepSpace2/StyleFrame/blob/a553377dcb964dd4cbea1840d37103ea7588cb40/styleframe/style_frame.py#L310)

> ```
> @classmethod
> def ExcelWriter(cls, path):
>     return pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl')
> ```

なので`mode='a'`は使えないでしょう。

---

**代替案は、[read_excel()](https://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styleframe.html?highlight=read_excel#styleframe.StyleFrame.read_excel) で読み込んで、そのstyleframeにデータを追加してから [to_excel()](https://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styleframe.html?highlight=read_excel#styleframe.StyleFrame.to_excel) を呼び出して書き出すことでしょう。**

Comment: 教えて頂きありがとうございました。pandasで書いたら解決しました。